# mysql use variable to decide if to execute insert

Tags: mysql, variables, if-statement

I have a table that must have only one row.
if this row exist don't do nothing
if there is no row insert data that does NOT contain the indexs field

I tried to use the below code but I get an error:

```
select count(id) into @myvar from customer;
IF(@myvar>0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customer 
    (dateformat, alarmDays, backup, pastPass, loginFails, passLength, timetochangepass)
    values('d,m,y',30, 30, 3, 5, 8, 90)
END
```

Comment: Control statements like `if` are only allowed in procedures, triggers, events and so on.

Comment: Every if needs a THEN and an END IF, every statement needs a terminator, an IF..END IF block in mysql does not require a BEGIN..END block, if this code is in a stored program(procedure,function,trigger,event) then an if exists test would be better (for readability as much as anything else)

Comment: You only anticipate 1 customer?

Comment: thank you all i will try using stored program

Comment: For a different method (and if you have control over your table), you could try [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4205181) with a dummy/default primary/unique key.